# CSS Positioning - How can you fix components in place?

Tags: html, css, layout, positioning

Example - http://appdist.me

What I'd like to do is have the keyboard SVG fixed to the bottom of the screen and take up half the screen height, with the Facebook logo always overlaying the 'Q' key, no matter how the window is resized.

I've been trying to do this for days. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <title>CSS Layout Problem</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="svg">
            <embed src="keyboard-gray.svg" id="keyboard"
                         type="image/svg+xml"
                         pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/svg/viewer/install/"/>
            <embed src="fb.svg" id="facebook"
                         type="image/svg+xml"
                         pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/svg/viewer/install/"/>
            <embed src="frame.svg" id="frame"
                         type="image/svg+xml"
                         pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/svg/viewer/install/"/>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
body{
    background-color: #333;
}

#svg{

} 

#facebook{
   position: fixed;
   width: 6%;
   height: 6%;
}

#frame{
   position: fixed;
   width: 100%;
   height: 47%;
   top: 2%;
   left: 0;
}

#keyboard{
   position: fixed;
   width: 100%;
   height: 50%;
   bottom: 2%;
   left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Just out of interest, why don't you make the facebook logo as part of the image? Is it to become a button?

Comment: Yeah that's the idea. My plan is to make a keyboard of links.

Comment: Haha that is if I can get it to work the way I want it to.

Comment: I could merge the SVG and put the links between the paths in the XML, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: ok - well I've added an answer below which links to an IBM page that should help you with that. Have fun!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to merge the images and make the SVG interactive, then you can use `<a>` tags in your xml (instead of `<g>`). Check out [this IBM link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-svgint/) for some ideas on how to achieve different types of interactivity.

Good luck - it looks like you have a fun project to play with.

Comment: Merged the SVG by hand using Illustrator and used the <a> tags as suggested to make the SVG interactive. Thanks! :D +1

Comment: No problem, glad it worked out. If you have time when it is finished, stick a comment under here - I'd like to check it out.

Comment: Seems to work okay, but having issues with cross-browser support.

Comment: Your SVG's show alright in all the browsers, so it looks like you might have over-complicated your CSS. Open a new question on StackOverflow or start your CSS from scratch and see what causes it to break in IE7 & 8

Comment: I did open up another question and it got resolved. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Position the `#facebook` absolutely too and set the z-index so that it shows above the keyboard.

```
#facebook{
  position: absolute;
  height: 12%;
  bottom: Y%;
  right: X%;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

Change `X` and `Y` so that it's above the Q key.

Comment: Doesn't seem to stay in place above the Q key when scaling the window.

Comment: Try using a percentage value instead of a pixel value.

Comment: No percentage for `right: X%` seems to affect the position of the Facebook logo. Might be getting somewhere though.